# How can i reload a sprite on my game in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm doing a project in python the goal is to make a little game.

In my main menu I have 3 buttons and I found a UI pack which gives me a sprite of buttons with one unpressed and one pressed. I want it to change the sprite when the button is pushed, but when I reload it doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong?

```py
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))
    pygame.display.set_caption('POKEMON')
    bg = pygame.image.load("./assets/img/lspkm.png")
    btn_new_Game = btn.Button("./assets/custombtn/btnbcnewgame.png", 305, 270, screen)
    btn_continue = btn.Button("./assets/custombtn/btnbccontinue.png", 305, 340, screen)
    btn_quit = btn.Button("./assets/custombtn/btnbcquit.png", 305, 410, screen)
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    btn_new_Game.draw()
    btn_continue.draw()
    btn_quit.draw()
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x, y = event.pos
                son = pygame.mixer.Sound("./assets/UIpack/Bonus/click2.ogg")
                if btn_quit.rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                    btn_quit.image = pygame.image.load("./assets/custombtn/btnacquit.png")
                    btn_quit.draw()
                    pygame.time.delay(3000)
                    return
```

***Edit1:***

As you can see, I have a button object to help me manage this:

```py
class Button :
    def __init__(self, image, x, y, screen):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.width = self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.image.get_height()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)
        self.screen = screen

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

    def update(self, image):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
```

Comment: You could load back the unpressed button on the mousebuttonup event, but there might be better options.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the button in this, and you only need to add the sprite changing on click.
You can create a list of button sprites i.e.

```
button1 = pygame.image.load('/resources/button1.png')
button2 = pygame.image.load('/resources/button2.png')
buttonClicked = pygame.image.load('/resources/buttonDark.png')
buttonList = [button1,button2,buttonClicked]
```

and then in your main game loop when you detect that the button has been pressed (mousebuttonup on the same position as the sprite)
you can execute this:

```
# pseudocode for you
when button = clicked
     i = 2
```

```
screen.blit(buttonList[i])
```

cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't match with my button class and even if i try to load a button over the older one it doesn't work